Why do I have multiple React imports in my Rollup bundle and how can I resolve it?
I'm using Rollup to bundle my custom npm react library, but I'm encountering multiple import statements for React and ReactDOM in the bundled output, and getting errors like cannot import (useContext | useState ...) of undefined in my host app. Here is an example of the import statements in the bundle:
import { jsx, Fragment, jsxs } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
import * as React from 'react';
import React__default, { useLayoutEffect, useEffect, forwardRef, useState, useRef, useCallback, useMemo, createContext, useContext, Fragment as Fragment$1, isValidElement, cloneElement, createElement, useId as useId$2, useReducer, useSyncExternalStore, createRef } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM__default, { createPortal, flushSync } from 'react-dom';


This duplication is causing issues with context and is leading to a larger bundle size. Here is my current Rollup configuration:
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import postcssImport from "postcss-import";
import { defineConfig } from "rollup";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default defineConfig([
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    onwarn(warning, warn) {
      // https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/5175
      if (warning.code === "MODULE_LEVEL_DIRECTIVE") {
        return;
      }
      warn(warning);
    },
    plugins: [
      external(),
      resolve({
        skip: ["react", "react-dom"],
      }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: "./dist",
        exclude: ["**/*.stories.tsx", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.test.tsx"],
      }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "src/styles/global.css",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.css", format: "es" }],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        extract: true,
        minimize: true,
        plugins: [postcssImport(), tailwindcss(), autoprefixer()],
      }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "es" }],
    plugins: [dts.default()],
  },
]);


package.json
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "xxx",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx --fix",
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "release": "standard-version && git push --follow-tags && npm publish"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1.5.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^26.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack": "^1.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-themes": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^8.1.10",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.1.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-regexp": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "postcss-import": "^16.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.11",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "rollup": "^4.19.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "standard-version": "^9.5.0",
    "storybook": "^8.1.10",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^2.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.1.1",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.19.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "classname-variants": "^1.5.0",
    "input-otp": "^1.2.4",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.4.5",
    "sonner": "^1.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  }
}


Questions:
Why are there multiple imports for React and ReactDOM in my bundled output?
How can I ensure that my bundle only includes a single import for each dependency to avoid context issues and reduce the bundle size?
What I’ve Tried:
I have listed react and react-dom as external dependencies in my Rollup config.
I have also ensured that my source code consistently imports React.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
I have listed react and react-dom as external dependencies in my Rollup config.
I have also ensured that my source code consistently imports React.
What am i expecting

To have a single import of react and react DOM in my build output
To get rid of the error cannot import (useContext | useState ...) of undefined in my host app


Can you share your package.json?

Hey @İbrahimAkar, i've just updated the question to include package.json. Thanks
